# Setting a user variable for MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

I need help with setting user variables for MySQL result.

`` SELECT ptype, COUNT(ptype) FROM `TABLE 2` GROUP BY ptype ORDER BY COUNT(ptype) ``

I would like to create a user variable for resulting value of all the types(TD=**5**,DT=**13**,...,etc)

How would I go about this?

dw

```js
<?$connector=mysqli_connect("localhost","", "","");

      
$res2=mysqli_query($connector, "SELECT ptype, COUNT(ptype) FROM `TABLE 2` GROUP BY ptype");


for (i = 0; i <12; i++) {
$carrier[i] = while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res3)) {echo $row['COUNT(carrier)'];}
      }
```

Comment: Need more info and more example of the code. What are you doing with the results? What error do you encounter when you test?

Comment: $res2=mysqli_query($connector, "SELECT ptype, COUNT(ptype) FROM `TABLE 2` GROUP BY ptype");

for (i = 0; i <12; i++) {
      $ptype[i] = while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) {echo $row['COUNT(ptype)'];}
      }

Comment: I am trying to create an array with those number values entered in.

$ptype[0]=5 // $ptype[1]=13,... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$ptype = array();
if($res2=mysqli_query($connector, "SELECT ptype, COUNT(ptype) AS pnum FROM TABLE 2 GROUP BY ptype")){
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) {
    $ptype[] = $row['pnum'];
  }
} else {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connector));
}
```

Comment: It seems like when I <?print_R ($ptype);?>

I am only getting array().

Thank you in advance for taking your time to help out!

Comment: This suggests that your WHILE loop did not add any info, so it looped 0 times. I updated my answer a bit for you.